# Drivine without nest.js?

Tags: typescript, drivine

I have an existing node-ts-express-setup that is not powered by nest.js. Unfortunatly the drivine docs and examples lack setup instructions without nest.js.

**Is it possible to run drivine without the need to import nest as dependency?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drivine does not need NestJS to run - the purpose of NestJS is to:

- Assemble a working module from the parts.
- Provide an example of code style.

However, at the present time `package.json` lists NestJS as a peer dependency. It is planned to split NestJS support into a separate npm module.

I suggest to raise a feature request on the [GitHub](https://github.com/liberation-data/drivine) repo, so that the following can be done:

- Split the NestJS parts into a separate module.
- Provide a sample app.

Comment: After a bit of research I decided to introduce nestjs into the project. I personally think that it is still a good idea to provide an out of the box solution for using drivine without nest since it is the best tool I found for querying graph databases. It should thus be available for a broader audience. Well done 

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad that you're enjoying Drivine. I will work on non-nest support ASAP. A few folks have asked for that in relation to using it with AWS Lambda. And also it would open possibility of using it from the browser.